# Flutter: Why am I getting the error "Route builders must never return null"?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, dart, flutter

I am new to flutter and below is my code

**homepage.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './product_page.dart';

class Homepage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Choco Factory"),
      ),
      body: HomepageUI(),
    );
  }
}

class HomepageUI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _HomepageUIState();
  }
}

class _HomepageUIState extends State<HomepageUI> {
  List<Map<String, String>> productsMap = [];

  _HomepageUIState() {
    productsMap
        .add({"title": "Cappuccino", "imageUrl": "assets/cappuccino.jpg"});
    productsMap.add(
        {"title": "Chocolate Cake", "imageUrl": "assets/chocolate_cake.jpg"});
    productsMap
        .add({"title": "Chocolates", "imageUrl": "assets/chocolates.jpg"});
    productsMap.add(
        {"title": "Hot Chocolate", "imageUrl": "assets/hot_chocolate.jpg"});
    productsMap.add({"title": "Naougat", "imageUrl": "assets/nougat.jpg"});
    productsMap.add(
        {"title": "White Chocolate", "imageUrl": "assets/white_chocolate.jpg"});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("Select Your Choco!"),
        Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: _listBuilder,
          itemCount: productsMap.length,
        )

            //child: Image.asset("assets/chocolates.jpg"),
            )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _listBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Card(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(productsMap[index]["imageUrl"]),
          Text(productsMap[index]["title"]),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Details"),
            color: Colors.green,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                ProductPage(productsMap[index]["title"],
                    productsMap[index]["imageUrl"]);
              }));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**product_page.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String  title, imageUrl;

  ProductPage(this.title,this.imageUrl);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Choco Factory"),
      ),
      body: ProductPageUI(title, imageUrl),
    );
  }
}

class ProductPageUI extends StatefulWidget {

  String title, imageUrl;

  ProductPageUI(this.title, this.imageUrl);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _ProductPageUIState();
  }
}

class _ProductPageUIState extends State<ProductPageUI> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return _productPageUIBuilder(widget.title, widget.imageUrl);
  }

  Widget _productPageUIBuilder(String title, String imageUrl) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(title),
        Image.asset(imageUrl),
        Text(
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper sodales nisi, ac ornare nisl ullamcorper vel. Aliquam nibh libero, consequat in arcu molestie, congue scelerisque elit. Integer eu ex in tellus iaculis egestas. Aliquam a molestie ante. Etiam eget magna id neque suscipit sollicitudin. Phasellus dolor erat, sagittis ut felis quis, faucibus finibus est. Aenean nunc justo, venenatis nec urna a, vehicula lacinia odio. Ut molestie velit vitae augue pulvinar dignissim. Integer tempus nisi dignissim nisl rutrum venenatis at in leo."),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When I click on the button, I get the following error. If there is no error, I should be navigating into another page "ProductPage".

```
I/flutter (31115): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (31115): The following assertion was thrown building Builder(dirty):
I/flutter (31115): The builder for route "null" returned null.
I/flutter (31115): Route builders must never return null.
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says, you're returning nothing in your route builder. You miss return statement

```
Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return ProductPage(productsMap[index]["title"], // you miss return here!
                    productsMap[index]["imageUrl"]);
              }));
```

Comment: Amazing, you got the point! I also noticed if replaced the braces around `ProductPage(....` with a Fat Arrow, the issue goes away too!

Comment: Yes. Since your build method is a single line of code and this line returns an object the arrow function notation fits very well. I put return statement  just to become more visible where was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

move productsMap in [initState](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)() function not in constructor

```
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    productsMap
        .add({"title": "Cappuccino", "imageUrl": "assets/cappuccino.jpg"});
    productsMap.add(
        {"title": "Chocolate Cake", "imageUrl": "assets/chocolate_cake.jpg"});
    productsMap
        .add({"title": "Chocolates", "imageUrl": "assets/chocolates.jpg"});
    productsMap.add(
        {"title": "Hot Chocolate", "imageUrl": "assets/hot_chocolate.jpg"});
    productsMap.add({"title": "Naougat", "imageUrl": "assets/nougat.jpg"});
    productsMap.add(
        {"title": "White Chocolate", "imageUrl": "assets/white_chocolate.jpg"});
  }
```

also your `Navigator.push`

```
Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => ProductPage(productsMap[index]["title"],
                productsMap[index]["imageUrl"])),
            );
```

Comment: Well, that seems not the issue.

Comment: yup just noticed that too and updated , but also for the initState my point is valid since I have seen mostly constructor being used to pass the data only

Answer (score 0):

You forget to return the widget in your builder function

```
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return ProductPage(productsMap[index]["title"],
                    productsMap[index]["imageUrl"]);
              }));
```

or if you prefer to use lambda function, the syntax would be:

```
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => ProductPage(
                      productsMap[index]["title"],
                      productsMap[index]["imageUrl"]),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                PageOne();
              }));
```

> Instead of just instantiating the page to be pushed in the builder method ,add it as a return param

```
Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return  PageOne();
              }));
```